When the data source is Excel Online, the format of the date and number columns is incorrect
I have an Excel file on SharePoint with a column for dates and another for numbers. I've formatted them as short date and number formats in Excel. However, when I use this Excel Online file as a data source in Power Apps, the dates in the Table and Form controls include time, and the number column is treated as text. How can I ensure that the number column remains a number format and the date column doesn't include time?
I know I can use Value(NumberColumn) to convert text to number. but it's not convenient.
